# как работает for loop в python

Tags: python, for

Подскажите пожалуйста **"guitar"** является переменной или это строка?
Если она является переменной то почему я не могу придать ей новое значение и изменить список таким способом?
Я знаю как решить эту задачу другим способом, но не могу понять почему данный способ не работает.

```
guitars = ['phil pro', 'epiphone', 'gibson']

for guitar in guitars:
    guitar = 'electric ' + guitar
    # print(guitar) -- если выводить отсюда, то все выводится как мне надо, но список при этом не изменяется 

print(guitars)

output:
['phil pro', 'epiphone', 'gibson']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guitar` - это переменная. На каждой итерации в ней оказывается содержимое очередного элемента списка. Для простоты восприятия считайте, что это копия. И когда вы присваиваете новое значение этой переменной, то это значение присваивается только ей, и никуда больше.

В этом можно удостовериться самостоятельно:

```
guitars = ['phil pro', 'epiphone', 'gibson']

for i, guitar in enumerate(guitars):
    print(i, "До   :", id(guitar), id(guitars[i]))
    guitar = 'electric ' + guitar
    print(i, "После:", id(guitar), id(guitars[i]))
```

```
0 До   : 140048368419120 140048368419120
0 После: 140048300344144 140048368419120
1 До   : 140048300509296 140048300509296
1 После: 140048300344144 140048300509296
2 До   : 140048300508464 140048300508464
2 После: 140048369136624 140048300508464
```

Как можно заметить, до присваивания нового значения переменная и соответствующее значение из списка эквивалентны, т.е. указывают на одно и то же значение в памяти. По после присваивания они уже указывают на разные значения.

Для модификации элемента списка следует обращаться к нему непосредственно по его индексу: `guitars[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно менять сам список, через индексы:

```
guitars = ['phil pro', 'epiphone', 'gibson']

for i, guitar in enumerate(guitars):
    guitars[i] = 'electric ' + guitar

print(guitars)
# ['electric phil pro', 'electric epiphone', 'electric gibson']
```

При итерации цикла `for guitar in guitars:` будет создана переменная `guitar`, в которую будут помещаться значения, а такая операция `guitar = 'electric ' + guitar` установит новое значение в переменную, старое не будет меняться

Строки вообще неизменяемый тип, поэтому поменять объект строки не получится - только новый создать

Но если хочется, то можно сделать объект и его менять:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Guitar:
    name: str


guitars = [Guitar('phil pro'), Guitar('epiphone'), Guitar('gibson')]

for guitar in guitars:
    guitar.name = 'electric ' + guitar.name

print(guitars)
# [Guitar(name='electric phil pro'), Guitar(name='electric epiphone'), Guitar(name='electric gibson')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for guitar in guitars:
```

При итерировании через `for` переменной `guitar` присваиваются по очереди **значения** из списка `guitars`. Но у этих значений и у этой переменной нет никакой обратной связи со списком, который перебирается. Как бы вы не меняли переменную цикла, эти никак не отразится на перебираемом списке.

В принципе, это не только в Питоне так, а, кажется, во всех языках. Переменная цикла - это просто переменная, которой что-то присваивается, а не ссылка на элементы перебираемой коллекции.